# LEFT JOIN slowing the query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT COALESCE(clnt.ename,clientid) NAME, sum(turnover)
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT csid,code,CP.ename
                FROM Senna 
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT csid,ename FROM C1) CP ON Senna.csid=CP.csid) clnt ON clientid = clnt.CODE

GROUP BY COALESCE(clnt.ename,clientid)
```

The above query is taking a lot of time to run and the reason for that is that the `Senna` and the `CP` tables are reference tables. I am trying to work a way to the improve the performance so that select clause for `code` field in the `senna` table is only picked for the `clientid` which are contained in the table `A`. The `left join` between `Senna` and the `CP` table is the reason for the issue of slowness but if somehow I can get the `Senna` table to fetch records based on only the `clientid` from `A` that will improve the performance massively.

Is there a way that the `clientid`s can be included in the `where` clause of the `senna` table so that when the `join` is being done with the `cp` table, the final `join`  of `clientid = clnt.CODE` is done on a smaller data set. Essentially, there are a number of records in the `senna` table which can be filtered out in order to improve performance. The ultimate goal is to pull the `ename`.

Bear in mind there would be 100s of `clientid` in table `A` as well.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to take from **senna** table just the values that are in table **A** then why are you left joining A with clnt? it would be INNER JOIN, isn't it? And on the question - of course you can limit senna table by A IDs by just joining them: `FROM Senna` -> `FROM (Senna s JOIN a on a.clientid = s.code)`. Will it help? I do not know. Won't it scan the A table twice? well, most probably it will. try the changes, investigate the execution plans, usage of indexes if any etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I understand what you need as an output. Please see whether the below Oracle query helps. If not, please explain your use-case more (say you want to list all the records from table A that matches records with table C1 etc or something similar to it for better understanding)

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(clnt.ename, clientid) NAME, 
  sum(turnover) 
FROM 
  A 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT senna.csid, 
      senna.code, 
      CP.ename 
    FROM 
      Senna senna 
      join C1 CP on senna.csid = CP.csid
  ) clnt ON clientid = clnt.CODE 
GROUP BY 
  COALESCE(clnt.ename, clientid);
```